# Avoid xtabular* environment wrapping on whole document

Tags: xtab

I have a large table which is 2 page in 2 column document, I have used xtabular* environment for it. but it wrapping around the whole document and fill the gaps!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference,9pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xtab}
\begin{document}
\topcaption{Caption}
\label{tab:seven}
\xentrystretch{-0.1}
\begin{xtabular*}{8.7cm}[t]{|p{2cm}|p{5.8cm}|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Subject}}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Description}\\
        \hline
        \textit{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \hline      
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Subject}}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Description}\\
        \hline
        \textit{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \hline      
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Subject}}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Description}\\
        \hline
        \textit{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b} \\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \emph{a} & {b}\\
        \hline

\end{xtabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here] is the resulting picture. I wish it could represent the problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: the document runs without error and works as expected, if you don't want the individual tables  to break at the bottom of the page you could use a sequence of standard `tabular` rather than using a package for tables that allow page breaking.

Comment: I add a picture, to represent the problem. as the table is long which need 2 page for it, I use `xtabular*`. The three table with in the `xtabular*` should place exactly after each other so I put them in same environment. the problem is that, the other table (table IX in the picture) is in the middle of my large table.

Comment: it is hard to guess your problem as your example only has one table environment.  if you mean you have a floating table that floats in to the xtab, put `\clearpage` before the multipage table, but otherwise edit the example so it is an example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, `\clearpage` solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to guess your problem as your example only has one table environment. if you mean you have a floating table that floats in to the xtab, put `\clearpage` before the multipage table.